# Disk space usage of file versions

Tags: 2010, versioning, file

Let's say I have checked in a 10 MB file to a document library. Now I change a single byte in the file and check in again.

How much disk space does the file use in the content database?

**~20 MB**  or **10 MB + some bytes / kilobytes** for the delta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010,each version of a document is stored separately in the database. It is By design.

As per Example, if a document of 10MB saved with 1byte change in it, File size in the Database will 10MB several bytes( due to metadata changes.).
Have a look on this [How does SharePoint store versions of customised pages?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37738/how-does-sharepoint-store-versions-of-customised-pages)

In latest version of SharePoint(2013 and 2016), MSFT introduced the Shredded Storage that's mean every time you store a file, it only save the delta.

http://sharepointpromag.com/blog/shredded-storage-sharepoint-2013-preview

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010, each time you check in a new version of the file, a new copy of the file is created. If Version 1 is 10MB, Version 2 is 11 MB, and Version 3 is 12 MB, then the content database is storing 33 MB of information for this item. According to Microsoft, "Regardless of the versioning control that you choose, it is important to remember that each version of a document stores a complete copy of the document in SQL Server and to consider what effect this might have on storage space."